# how to use "dba_tab_privs" in DataContext.executequery()

Tags: java, oracle11g, datacontext

I need to get the list of all the privileges on a `oracle database schema` using DataContext.executeQuery("") function in java.
I am using following query to get the list, it is working when I execute query in Oracle SQL Developer UI.

```
SELECT grantee, privilege
FROM dba_sys_privs
WHERE grantee = '<username>'
ORDER BY privilege;
```

When I Use the query in dataContext.executequery("Query") it gives "Not capable of parsing dba_sys_privs" error.

Comment: Are you getting the same error when querying the `user_sys_privs` dictionary view? The `dba_*` dictionary views are accessible only by users with `DBA` or `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` system privilege.

Comment: Yes getting same error with 'user_sys_privs `